# BI publisher template builder for powerpoint

Tags: templates, office-addins, obiee, bi-publisher

I was going to make Excel and PowerPoint templates and upload them to BI publisher. In this regard, I installed BI publisher desktop tool and did what I want for Excel one (by the BI publisher tab which was added to Excel). I mean this:

[image]

But I did not find any BI publisher tab in PowerPoint. By searching on the internet, I have found that this feature dose not exist for PowerPoint .

**Is this fact true?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, BIP does not integrate with PowerPoint.